# Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e'

Tags: python, django

I am getting errors from Django 1.7 application hosted in Digital ocean.

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

```
Request repr():
<WSGIRequest
path:/xmlrpc.php,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_HOST': '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64;  rv:10.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '181.214.92.100',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/xmlrpc.php',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': '/xmlrpc.php',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '181.214.92.100',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '80',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': '\x80\xc7\xda\x9e',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/18.0',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x7fb05e3e1280>,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fb0663e01e0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at    0x7fb063c1b7a0>,
 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7fb05e3bf810>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

I have set ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] in my base file. What is the cause of this error and how can i resolve this ?